# how to Integrate fingerprint scanner ZK software in OPENERP 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have the need to integrate the fingerprint  'ZK software iface 302' to OpenERP 7.if someone cab give me  best way to communicate the fingerprint and  OpenERP.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the fingerprint scanner SDK. I integrated one using Java which worked quite well, but only for v6: http://timothysolomon.co.za/work/openerp-authentication-using-uareu-fingerprint-scanner/

Comment: there is any solution for using it in openerp V7 or v8